# DataTemplate for Panorama header template displays nothing at run-time (Windows Phone/XAML)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

I have a Windows Phone 8 project using C#.  I created a DataTemplate in my App.xaml file as a resource.  I then set the HeaderTemplate property for my PanoramaItem object for that page to use that DataTemplate as a static resource.  **When I run the app nothing displays in the area reserved for the Header.** However, the same XAML code block that I turned into a DataTemplate works fine when it is inline on the page that contains the PanoramaItem object.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Here's the original inline XAML code for the PanoramaItem detail page:

```
    <phone:Panorama x:Name="PanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="{StaticResource CustomApplicationBackgroundImage}" SelectionChanged="panoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos_SelectionChanged">
        <phone:Panorama.Title>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                <Image Height="85" Width="85" Source="http://appstudiodata.blob.core.windows.net/apps/1383/db936107-bce6-41a2-9d95-1d342f66c6bb/res/Logo-b3883645-a6cd-4cc8-82be-97c87a266656.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,10,5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="92" Text="Robot Videos" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomTitleApplicationTextBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:Panorama.Title>

        <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0" Margin="0,0,0,25" >
            <phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,7,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentYouTubeVideo.Title, Converter={StaticResource SanitizeString}}" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" FontSize="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="420" Height="240"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
            <ctl:FlipControl NextElementCommand="{Binding NextpanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" PreviousElementCommand="{Binding PreviouspanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" ShowPreviousButton="{Binding HasPreviouspanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" ShowNextButton="{Binding HasNextpanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}">
                <ctl:FlipControl.InnerContent>
                    <Grid Margin="10,5,5,5">    
                        <ScrollViewer>
                                <ctl:YouTubePlayer Margin="0,10" MaxHeight="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" VideoId="{Binding CurrentYouTubeVideo.VideoId, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultNoImageValue}}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ctl:FlipControl.InnerContent>
            </ctl:FlipControl>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
```

Here is the XAML code for the DataTemplate I created in the ApplicationResources section of my App.xaml file:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,7,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentYouTubeVideo.Title, Converter={StaticResource SanitizeString}}" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" FontSize="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="420" Height="240"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is the new XAML code for the PanoramaItem that is now set to use the DataTemplate:

```
    <phone:Panorama x:Name="PanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}" Background="{StaticResource CustomApplicationBackgroundImage}" SelectionChanged="panoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos_SelectionChanged">
        <phone:Panorama.Title>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                <Image Height="85" Width="85" Source="http://appstudiodata.blob.core.windows.net/apps/1383/db936107-bce6-41a2-9d95-1d342f66c6bb/res/Logo-b3883645-a6cd-4cc8-82be-97c87a266656.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,10,5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="92" Text="Robot Videos" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomTitleApplicationTextBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:Panorama.Title>

        <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0" Margin="0,0,0,25" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate}">
            <ctl:FlipControl NextElementCommand="{Binding NextpanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" PreviousElementCommand="{Binding PreviouspanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" ShowPreviousButton="{Binding HasPreviouspanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}" ShowNextButton="{Binding HasNextpanoramaMilitaryRobots_DetailVideos0}">
                <ctl:FlipControl.InnerContent>
                    <Grid Margin="10,5,5,5">    
                        <ScrollViewer>
                                <ctl:YouTubePlayer Margin="0,10" MaxHeight="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" VideoId="{Binding CurrentYouTubeVideo.VideoId, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultNoImageValue}}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ctl:FlipControl.InnerContent>
            </ctl:FlipControl>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
```

Comment: I believe you need to actually set the header, in order to provide a DataContext to the HeaderTemplate.  Try this?  `Header="{Binding}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate}"`

Comment: @McGarnagle - I just tried that and I get the error message "Header is not recognized or not accessible".